# Tor Browser: Is it safe to connect to Tor via a proxy server?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, proxy, socks, ssh

When using the Tor Browser, is it safe to connect to Tor via a proxy server? There is an SSH connection between the proxy server and my computer: `ssh me@proxyserver -D localhost:9999`. In the Tor Browser's preferences, I configure the browser to connect to Tor via the SOCKS5 proxy at `localhost:9999`:

[image: Tor Browser proxy settings]

Is it safe to connect to Tor in this manner? Will the proxy server be able to eavesdrop on the data sent to and from the Tor Browser?

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the exact menu that you're editing?

Comment: @Steve Screenshot added.

Answer (score 0):

yes it's safe, because the directory services' keys are hardcoded into the Tor source code itself so no data breach will be possible. The proxy is just a way to connect to the dir's and peers. But if you're behind the proxy - then you will be unable to accept `ORPort` incoming connections and it's not good for the speed and decentralization of the network.